# Pyspark create column and populate it in different steps

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1
         Day     Hour     Values1
        Monday    7        65      
        Monday    8        66
        Monday    9        66
        Tuesday   7        68
        Tuesday   9        68
        Tuesday   10       58
```

I want to create a column 'Tag' where each row will have a different string based on different conditions. For example, if day==Monday and Hour==7 and values1==65 then create column Tag and put value 'Blue' and so on..

Expected Output:

```
      Day     Hour     Values1     Tag
    Monday    7        65         'Blue' 
    Monday    8        66         'Red'
    Monday    9        66         'Yellow'
    Tuesday   7        68         'Blue'
    Tuesday   9        68         'Black'
    Tuesday   10       58         'Black'
```

I tried to do it by creating the column tag and then manually iterating over each cell and use if conditions. This works but obviously is really naive and slow. Is there any solution that exploits groupby or something similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `when()` and `otherwise()`

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import *
  df.withColumn("tag", when((col("day")=='monday') & (col('hour')==7) & (col('Values1')==65), "Blue))
```

you can use mutiple `when()` along with `otherwise()`

```
  df.withColumn("tag", 
                  when(condition1,value)
                  .when(condition2,value)
                 .otherwise(value))
```